# Use LSTM to forecast Precipitation

Tags: deep-learning, time-series, lstm, forecast

I build a LSTM to forecast Precipitation, but it doesn't work well.
My code is very simple and data is very short only **contains 720 points**.
**i use MinMaxScale to scale the data.**
this is my code, **seq_len = 12**

```
model = Sequential([
layers.LSTM(2, input_shape=(SEQ_LEN, 1),
layers.Dense(1)])
```

my data is like this [image]

and the output compares with true value like this[image]

I use adam and mae loss function, epoch=10
is it underfitting? or is this simple net can't do this work?
r2_score is no more than 0.55
please tell me how to adjust it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

there are so many options;

- first of all it would be better to define the optimized window size by changing the periods of the sequences
- The second option would be changing the batch-size of the dataset
- Change optimizer into SGD cause of few datapoints and before training model define the best values for learning rate by setting Learning Rate Schedule callback
- Try another model architecture with convolution layers and etc
- Sometimes it would be a trick to help model performance by setting lambda layer after the last layer to scale up values cause of lstm default activation function is tanh.